# How can I recover from a failed flash with an EZ Planck (Teensy powered keyboard): device not accepting address, error -71?

Tags: linux, keyboard, flashing

I'm trying to flash my EZ Planck from ZSA Technology Labs through their tool, [Wally](https://www.zsa.io/wally/). When it asked me to hit the reset button, I hit it a few times. It went to a screen that said it was flashing and not to unplug the power. It was stuck there. I think after one of my resets took, it started flashing and then I hit the button again before the GUI updated.

Anyway, now I'm getting these errors in `dmesg`,

```
new full-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
Device not responding to setup address.
Device not responding to setup address.
device not accepting address 68, error -71
new full-speed USB device number 69 using xhci_hcd
Device not responding to setup address.
Device not responding to setup address.
device not accepting address 69, error -71
```

My keyboard is no longer recognized. How can I resolve these errors and unbrick the keyboard? I'm using Linux to flash the EZ Planck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions call for pressing the reset button. You can still do that:

- Run `sudo watch -n0.1 dmesg`
- Press and hold the reset button on the Planck. It takes around 5 seconds, eventually you should see this,

  ```
  new full-speed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
  New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=df11, bcdDevice=22.00
  New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  Product: STM32  BOOTLOADER
  Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
  SerialNumber: 206A33622031
  ```
- Try flashing again with Wally.
- After the flash takes, and the keyboard resets you should see this in the terminal you're running `watch` in,

  ```
  USB disconnect, device number 121
  new full-speed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
  New USB device found, idVendor=3297, idProduct=c6cf, bcdDevice= 0.01
  New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
  Product: Planck EZ Glow
  Manufacturer: ZSA Technology Labs
  ZSA Technology Labs Planck EZ Glow as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/0003:3297:C6CF.07EF/input/input1909
  ```

When you hit reset, you power cycle and boot into the bootloader on the [Teensy board](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/) that the keyboard was built with. If you fail to flash the EZ Planck firmware, you still have a Teensy board in the EZ Planck that you can reset and enter the bootloader with. Then you can flash. The `wally` tool doesn't flash an EZ Planck, **it flashes the Teensy making it an EZ Planck.**